# asp.net page getting System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Query timeout expired

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is working 99% of the time.  I have one instance depending on the parameters will pull a large amount of data.  It takes about 30 seconds running it directly on SQL server but will time out on asp page.

How do I increase my timeout value. I've updated my connectionstring properties but that is not working?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringTest" connectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=W2K8-CM;Persist Security Info=True;Password=;User ID=;Initial Catalog=VELIVE;Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should resolve the problem adding in your connection string the token `Connection Timeout=HowManySecondsYouWant`

The default value is 30 seconds.

Comment: This recommendation has no effect. Still times out in 30 seconds.